# For Loop that increments and inserts a value from the previous row

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, percentage

I am trying to increase a value of the last entry inserted into a MySQL table by x%, then inserting that value into the database and continuing until the loop ends, starting with the base value of 100.

Let's say I start with the a `$base_value` of 100 at row number one and I would like to increase that value by 25% in an iteration. So, in row number two I would like 100 increased by 25%. In row number three, the value in row number two increased by 25%, etc, the loop stops when it reaches 100. How can this be done ?

```
$base_value = 100;
$increase_by; // x percent

for($i = 1; $i = 100; $i++)
{
    mysql_query("insert into table values(
       '',
       '$i',
       ''
    )");
}
```

Comment: First of all, unless PHP is doing something weird, your `for` loop conditional seems wrong.  The second statement should probably be `$i <= 100`, otherwise I don't think the loop will run at all because the condition will start out as false.

Comment: You might be able to do this in pure SQL. Just do a `SELECT` to get the last row, retrieve the value you want, calculate +25% (value/100*25) and then use the new value for your `INSERT`.

Comment: @David - It looks more like an [infinite loop](http://viper-7.com/D0LXfe).

Comment: Row one in the dabatase has a value of 100 ? Or is it $base_value in PHP that is set to 100 when you start the loop ?

Comment: the base value is 100 when the loop is started.

Comment: Ok, adjusted the question so it's clear.

Comment: @David it would be an infinite loop, as it would repeatedly set $i to 100. Had he written `$i == 100`, it would indeed never run.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
$base_value = 100;
$increase_by; // x percent

for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    mysqli_query("insert into table values(
       '$base_value',
       '$i',
       ''
    )");
    $base_value = $base_value + ($base_value * $increase_by);
}
```

A few things to note:

- I've replaced `mysql_query` with `mysqli_query`, and I suggest you do the same.  [PHP also suggests this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).
- I changed the terminating condition in your `for` loop from `$i = 100` to `$i <= 100`.  If the former even worked at all, I'm not sure what the behavior would be.  It's *setting* `$i` in the conditional, which first of all is something you *never* want to do.  But this also means that either it'll never run or it'll run indefinitely, depending on how it interprets the assignment statement as a boolean value.  Neither of these options are desirable.
- This math assumes that `$increase_by` is of the correct decimal places.  If instead you're representing the concept of "25%" with an actual value of "25" then you'll have to adjust the math to account for this discrepancy.
- The SQL query itself was otherwise untouched because I assume it's a contrived example.  But just in case it's worth pointing out that you have a third unnecessary value and that your table is named `table`, which is probably a bad idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun and assuming value at first row is zero, an alternative would be this SQL query with uid being the primary key.

```
$base_value = 100;
$factor = 1.25; // Take previous value and times it by 125%

// ...

mysqli_query(
"INSERT INTO table (my_value)
SELECT (my_value * $factor) AS my_value FROM table ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 1"
);

$base_value *= $factor;

// ...
```

However, don't count on this working reliably if you have concurrent operations and, without testing, my spider sense says that a snag will be hit on the first iteration if the table is empty. Anyway, feel free to comment. Obviously, @David's solution is more reasonable :)